# Custom class Set Intersection not working in Dart

Tags: dart, set

The Following is the code:

```
   final Set<Item> _set1 = {
      Item(id: 1, name: "carrot"),
      Item(id: 2,name: "apple"),
      Item(id: 3,name: "mango")
   };

  final Set<Item> _set2 = {
     Item(id: 1, name: "carrot"),
   };
  print(_set1.intersection(_set2));
```

My Class looks like this:

```
class Item{
  int id;
  String name;
Item({required this.id,required this.name});
}
```

Required output:

```
{Instance of 'Item'}
//carrot which is common
```

Output that came out of above code:

```
{}
```

Comment: Does the `Item` class override `==` and `.hashCode`?

Comment: I have added the class snippet now

Comment: Yeah, your issue are what mmcdon20 describes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set literal in dart creates a [LinkedHashSet](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet-class.html), which has the following requirement:

> The elements of a `LinkedHashSet` must have consistent [Object.==](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) and [Object.hashCode](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html) implementations. This means that the `==` operator must define a stable equivalence relation on the elements (reflexive, symmetric, transitive, and consistent over time), and that `hashCode` must be the same for objects that are considered equal by `==`.

In other words you must override `==` and `hashCode` in your `Item` class.

```dart
void main() {
  final Set<Item> _set1 = {
    Item(id: 1, name: "carrot"),
    Item(id: 2, name: "apple"),
    Item(id: 3, name: "mango")
  };

  final Set<Item> _set2 = {
    Item(id: 1, name: "carrot"),
  };
  print(_set1.intersection(_set2));
}

class Item {
  int id;
  String name;
  Item({required this.id, required this.name});
  
  // add an implementation for hashCode and ==
  @override
  int get hashCode => Object.hash(id, name);
  
  @override
  operator ==(Object other) =>
      other is Item && id == other.id && name == other.name;
}
```